# Can I use Expression<Func<T, bool>> and reliably see which properties are referenced in the Func<T, bool>?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I'm writing something in the flavour of `Enumerable.Where` in that takes a predicate of the form `Func<T, bool>`. If the underlying `T` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, I'd like to be a bit more intelligent about re-evaluating the predicate.

I'm thinking about changing it to use `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, and then using the expression tree to find out which properties are used in the predicate. Then I can have my `PropertyChanged` handler be a bit more intelligent.

My question: is this feasible? If the predicate's simple (e.g. `x => x.Age > 18`), then the `Expression` seems to have everything I need in it. Are there scenarios where I won't be able to see which properties are referenced?

Comment: ...and the correct answer is to avoid all this entirely and just use ContinuousLinq: http://clinq.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll be able to see everything *directly* referenced. Of course, if someone passes

```
x => ComputeAge(x) > 18
```

then you won't necessarily know that `ComputeAge` refers to the `Age` property.

The expression tree will be an accurate representation of exactly what's in the lambda expression.

Comment: Cool, so if it's a simple expression, I'm good. If it's a complex expression, I'll have to fall back onto blindly re-evaluating the predicate.

Comment: @Roger: Even if it only contains properties, you need to consider whether those properties will refer to others. For example, suppose the `Age` property uses the `DateOfBirth` property... then a change to `DateOfBirth` should trigger re-evaluation, but the expression won't directly expose that dependency :(

Comment: Bah, so the answer (for my purposes) is "No: you can't reliably see which properties are used". Fair enough: blind re-evaluation is the solution then.

Answer (score 1):

Small code example of a visitor that would find *directly* referenced properties.

```
public class PropertyAccessFinder : ExpressionVisitor {
    private readonly HashSet<PropertyInfo> _properties = new HashSet<PropertyInfo>();

    public IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> Properties {
        get { return _properties; }
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node) {
        var property = node.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if (property != null)
            _properties.Add(property);

        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}

// Usage:
var visitor = new PropertyAccessFinder();
visitor.Visit(predicate);
foreach(var prop in visitor.Properties)
    Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
```