# How to get names from expression property?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Get method name and type using lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273941/get-method-name-and-type-using-lambda-expression)
>   [Can I use Expression<Func<T, bool>> and reliably see which properties are referenced in the Func<T, bool>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665980/can-i-use-expressionfunct-bool-and-reliably-see-which-properties-are-referen)

Hi,

I want to have a method, which I can use like this

```
<% Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Property, Helper.GetAttributes<ViewModel>(x=>x.PropertyA)) %>
```

The method header  looks like this

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetAttributeValues<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> myParam)
```

but how do i find out the name of PropertyA? i need to do some checks before returning the right attributes.
thanks in advance..

cheers

PS: thanks to driis post [How to get names from expression property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554427/how-to-get-names-from-expression-property/4554457#4554457) i found the solution

it is

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetAttributeValues<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> myParam)
{
    var item = myParam.Body as UnaryExpression;
    var operand = item.Operand as MemberExpression;
    Log.Debug(operand.Member.Name);
}
```

Comment: I think it should stay open. @GvS's answer is really good and applicable to  doing this sort of work in an asp.net mvc application. None of the other questions we've marked as dupes have his answer.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression -- there's a gotcha if you want nested properties (i.e. `Thing1.Thing2` from `o => o.Thing1.Thing2` -- see [my attempt for an alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17220748/1037948)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be:

```
string propertyName = ((MemberExpression) myParam.Body).Member.Name;
```

In production code, you should probably check the Expression type before the cast and throw an appropiate exception if the expression passed in is not MemberExpression.

Comment: thanks for you fast response, but i get the error InvalidCastexception, cannot convert from "System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression" to "System.Ling.Expressions.MemberExpression"

Comment: thanks again,your hint with memberexpression has shown me the right way to solve this problem :-)  i've updated my original post

Answer (score 2):

Create an instance of a [ModelMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407408%28v=VS.98%29.aspx) class:

```
var data = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<T, object>(myParam);
```

And now you can get all the information you need, with respect to attributes used on your model:

```
var propName = data.PropertyName;
var label = data.DisplayName;
```